# Android Universal image loader, stop retry

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use the UIL lib in my app, I get the images from my Amazon S3 server. 
 I've overridden the `BaseImageDownloader` class :

```
protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageId, Object extra)
        throws IOException {

    TransferManager manager = AmazonParams.getTransferManager();


    File file = null; 
    GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(AmazonParams.BUCKET, imageId);
    try{

        file = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(imageId);

        Download d = manager.download(req, file);

        while (d.isDone() == false);

    }catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }

    return new FileInputStream(file);


}
```

but when I have a 404 error at the server (no such image) the UIL, and I return `null` the UIL keeps retrying to load the image over and over. If there is no such image I'd like it not to try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIL doesn't retry image loading itself. If you return **null** then you'll got 
`onLoadingFailed(...)` callback. If you call `displayImage(...)` for the same URL again then UIL will try to load image again.

If you want to prevent it then you should keep "bad" URLs somewhere and not call ImageLoader for these URLs, or return null in ImageDownloader fro these URLs.