# Stop Retry in UIL android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, image-loading, resque-retry

I am using `nostra Android-Universal-Image-Loader` in my application.

When there is no image on the server with that url, it's retrying too many times.

How can I make it stop retrying?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Even when using onLoadingFailed using a listener, I noticed Universal Image Loader will retry up to 10 times before displaying my backup image per onLoadingFailed.

Comment: No i managed with picasso

Comment: As the UIL author said, UIL do not retry itself.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110153/android-universal-image-loader-stop-retry